# Only allow living breathing user to issue a command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal, tty

I have an application that accepts input from stdin, let's call this application `suman-f` which can be run via the command line. I'd like to limit the input to the real human user only and not allow input from automated programs. The reason for this is because if multiple processes are sending information to stdin, it will get garbled, as there is only one information channel but multiple communicators.

Is there a way to prevent anything but a human executing `suman-f` via a terminal?

Or if there is some magical way to multiplex stdin, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple processes sending information to stdin"?

Comment: Why would input from automated programs mean garbled input?

Comment: If you have 5 programs writing to the stdin of another program X, how does X piece together the messages?

Comment: not sure why this question got a downvote...@MichaelHomer multiple processes could potentially write to suman-f stdin simultaneously...not sure how else to describe it

Comment: Yes, it's called a Turing Test.

Comment: couldn't you check if it was a tty or not?

Comment: _"multiple processes are sending information to stdin"_  That is not normal.  People will be better able to help you if you describe exactly how this is happening.

Comment: it's not that normal, but it's not that hard to imagine either right? UDP messages arriving to a UDP server has the same kind of problem, it's *not* necessarily easy to multiplex (I believe).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand well the logic behind your question.  If multiple human users send information to stdin at the same time, it would get garbled too.

Comment: I couldn't think of a better word than eponymous - "suman-f" is the program name and it is run by executing `suman-f` at the command line.

Comment: yeah. it was a misuse of the word, I removed it from the question

Comment: this seems like a pretty legit question with interesting ramifications, wish people would think outside the box, or appreciate a question outside of the box.

Comment: Is this question about multiplexing or about preventing future simulated human brains from logging on? It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **no**.

Unix system has no way to know if stdin of a particular process is handled by a human.

## tty

your best approximation is `tty`. (see `man tty`).

tty (terminal) are the way to interact with system ( see [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) ).

This is how it works

```
if tty -s
then
    echo a human might be reading "or not)"
else
    echo output is a file
fi
```

in other word

- if `tty -s` return `false`, you know output is a file (not a user),
- if `tty -s` return `true`, you don't know.

This allow different formating (like `ls`), or prevent from interactive usage.

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking. an approximation is ok.

Comment: How would `tty` help? (Think `ssh -t...` as just one example.)

Comment: that's why I say "approximation"

Comment: this guy gets the question, why is it so hard for other people to understand the question.